Can I replace a GFCI outlet in a bathroom with an outlet having USB ports?
I’m wanting to replace the GFCI outlet in my master bathroom to one with USB plugs due to my wife’s new electric toothbrushes requiring USB to charge. Is it possible to do? Or should I just buy a brick and keep it plugged in there? New homeowner looking for advice

Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how to respond to answers.

My last beard trimmer came with a USB charging cable and an A/C brick for it too. I suspect this is going to become more and more common.

you CAN NOT go from gfci to not-gfci.  NO

Buy a brick!
USB outlets built into walls are overpriced and underspec'ed even the day you install them and they become obsolete like potato salad in the sun.
The Lowe's one in the other answer is 10W and costs $45.   10W?  That's like, 2010?
I know it'll be fine for the toothbrush but think a little more generally.
For that price, or less, you can buy a 100W 4 port GAN charger that at least today is state of the art and when it fails or becomes obsolete you don't have to remove it from the wall or replace the GFCI with it.
Update
Having thought about all the comments, I'm swayed by a combination of them, and I'll suggest the circumstances where you might prefer to install a combo outlet:

Counter space at the outlet is very limited, and/or very near the sink so you will never have large numbers of electrical things all being used/charged at once. (@MonkeyZeus)
You can find a combo outlet with at a USB-A port that is QC3 or better, and a USB-C port that is 25W PD or better (@Manasseh), the outlet is UL listed, made by a company with a significant presence in the USA or in your country, and sold by a retailer in your country. (@Dan Is Fiddling...)
That combo outlet is worth whatever it costs to you, versus a cheaper brick if you already have a GFCI outlet, or versus $0 if you have old chargers to plug into your GFCI outlet that are good enough for your needs.

If all the above are true ... I would go this way.  A 25W PD charger may not be state of the art but it will be a very good 80/20 solution, it will charge what you probably need to charge, fast enough, and take no space in the bathroom.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


GFCI outlet in my master bathroom

You can't replace GFCI with non-GFCI in a bathroom. Technically, you could if you replaced the breaker with a GFCI/breaker, but that will cost more.
However, you can replace a GFCI with a GFCI that also has USB, such as this Leviton from Home Depot:

Alternatively, you can replace the existing junction box with a larger one and chain from the GFCI to a non-GFCI receptacle with USB. I did that in my kitchen because you can never have too many receptacles.

This is another option, but obviously makes it impossible to see if the GFCI has tripped (but in fairness, it should be fairly obvious to check when your plugged devices don't get juice): https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-5-Outlet-Surge-Protector-Wall-Tap-with-USB-A-and-USB-C-Ports-43650/310041096

My upvote for an accurate answer cancels my down one for what a POS the example is.  :(. Net zero

you can never have too many receptacles Yes you can. They are usually placed on the wall you expected to have [something] and the [something] is now on the other wall, devout of receptacles.

@WoJ But the solution then is to add more receptacles.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact When renovating my apartment I suggested having receptacles all along the rail (we have a rail on the bottom of the wall that carries the cables, you cannot dig in the wall). Every 10 cm - this way something will always match. My wife had a different opinion, so we do not have that. And more or less every receptacle is misplaced or missing. On the serious side - I saw solutions where you plug your receptacle into the rail where you need this but the price was astronomical.

In a kitchen you can easily have too many receptacles because just adding more of them leads to situations when you try using too many countertop appliances at once and tripping the breaker.  What you can never have too many of in the kitchen is circuits.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I believe in one outlet for every 2 ft of linear counter space, with 2-3 outlets per circuit... More then that is overkill.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight But then your 25 toasters are just going to trip the main breaker ;)

I am certain the circuit breakers have to be 20AMPs to the bathroom.  I noticed that is a 15AMP GFCI outlet.  I thought 20AMP GFCI outlets were required in the bathroom, but now not sure.  Seeing conflicting information.

@rjt The circuit must be 20A. But a 20A circuit (in general, not just when GFCI is involved such as kitchen and bathroom) can have 15A receptacles as long as there are at least two receptacles, and a typical duplex receptacle counts as two.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight: My great aunt's house had four different circuits feeding the kitchen island; each of these was in fact a single outlet on a bedroom circuit (tied into the lights and sockets in that bedroom). She wanted to have waffle parties.

The link in your answer has broken, it return access denied

@Ferrybig works for me. I suspect home depot has it geofenced.
